# Is this ADC circuit safe for when my Pro Micro is off?

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have the following little circuit:

[image]

This voltage divider is used by my [Pro Micro](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10999) to detect when `CB_VCC` is powered. `CB_SENSE` leads to an ADC pin on my Pro Micro.

Is this circuit safe for when the Pro Micro is off, but `CB_VCC` is powered? I'm dealing with 3.3V (that's what's powering the Pro Micro and `CB_VCC`). Do I need a series resistor before the ADC pin?

Comment: I have no technical reasoning to back this up, but from experience, as long as your not applying a voltage greater then what the chip can handle you should be okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have voltages higher than the supply voltage on a microcontroller. The controller indeed has clamping diodes to protect the inputs against too high and too low voltages, but it's a Bad Habit™ to use them intentionally. \$\mathrm{CB_{SENSE}}\$ won't be higher than 0.67 V and you would think this is harmless, but on page 378 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7766.pdf) it says under Absolute Maximum Ratings:

> "Voltage on any Pin except RESET and VBUS with respect to Ground: -0.5V to Vcc+0.5V"

So even that low 0.67 V is too high. Your gut feeling may say that voltage and current are so low that it's probably harmless, and I would agree if the datasheet didn't say otherwise:

> "Stresses beyond those listed under “Absolute
>   Maximum Ratings” may **cause permanent damage
>   to the device**. This is a stress rating only and
>   functional operation of the device at these or
>   other conditions beyond those indicated in the
>   operational sections of this specification is not
>   implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating
>   conditions **for extended periods may affect
>   device reliability**. *(emphasis mine)*

So, while you would want to take the risk for your one-off project I wouldn't do this for my 10k/year design.

Comment: Ok, thanks! How would you fix the circuit to make it safe?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - What's that CB_VCC? Can't you switch it off with the microcontroller's power?

Comment: Basically, the situation is this: this circuit is part of a larger circuit that i embedded in a guitar hero drumset. The drumset has a control box that is what normally powers the drumset circuitry. Control box power is cb_vcc. The arduino can also power the drumset circuitry, but not the control box. I also don't want the control box powering the arduino, so I use schottky diodes. I'll post a schematic in just a few seconds.

Comment: Here is my schematic. Note that this is for a tutorial and DIY project, so I make the assumption that the control box and Arduino won't be powered at the same time. http://i.imgur.com/gJsnX.png

Comment: @SimpleCoder - This kind of schematic is difficult to read. I always have to scan all the parts to see if the net I'm looking at appears on them. A more common schematic would show this more clearly. Anyway, as I understand it you're using CB_SENSE just to detect the voltage, not actually measure it? If that's the case, can't you drive an NPN transistor or MOSFET from CB_VCC, and use a pullup to VCC. Then a low level on the NPN's collector means CB_VCC is present. Switching off the Pro-Micro will also make the pullup go to zero.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - R6 is also a problem, even more than the divider. You get the full CB_VCC on the Pro-Micro's input.

Comment: Sorry about the schematic. You are correct, I only need to detect CB_VCC, not measure it. But, that feature is unnecessary as far as my project goes. I think I'll just scrap that to avoid further mistakes on my part. As for R6, can I replace that with a PNP transistor on the Arduino side? The only thing the Arduino does with that line is to pull it to ground to enable the buffers. R6 is there to disable the buffers by pulling OE high when the control box is powering the circuit.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Why can't you connect CB_VCC directly to the 74125 buffers enable inputs? Then they will be disabled if the control box has power.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - OK, I see. Other idea: the Pro-Micro is aware of the CB_VCC state through the CB_SENSE input, right? So can't you use one of the free I/O's to control the enables?

Comment: That's what I do currently. When the Arduino is on, it pulls OE low. Since this is a DIY project, I make the assumption that the user hasn't plugged in the Arduino while the control box is on. I think I'll just get an active high version of the chip, and tie OE to Vcc on the Arduino with a pulldown to ground.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it (including indulging my side questions).

Answer (score 1):

I think Michael is correct.  Here's some reasoning to back it up.

When CB_VCC = 3.3V, the Thevenin equivalent circuit connected to the ADC pin is a 0.67V source in series with 7.96k\$\Omega\$.  The *maximum* current this circuit could supply the ADC pin is then about 85\$ \mu A\$.

Comment: He didnt really say what CB_VCC would be energized at. May not be 3.3v.

Comment: It is 3.3v, second to last line of my question.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: this sounds good, thanks for responding. I have heard that if a pin is something like 0.5 v greater than the power to the chip, the reverse protection diodes on the pin will conduct current into the chip, powering it. Since the current the circuit can provide is so low, is that why this doesn't occur?

Comment: Similarly, if I have a 10k resistor pulling up a digital pin while the pro micro is off, will that cause any problems?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - the reason why the controller doesn't get powered this way is that the voltage is too low. You have 0.67 V and lose 0.5 V of it in the protection diode, so that's 0.17 V left. If you would want to draw current from it it would even go lower, to 0 V at 21.8 uA.

Comment: @SimpleCoder, what is the voltage on the ADC pin when the Pro Micro is off and CB_VCC = 3.3.V?

Comment: I'm not sure. The pin is pulled up to 3.3v through a 10k.

Comment: Then measure the pin voltages that are pulled up when the micro is unpowered.  If the pin voltages are within the maximum ratings, you should be OK for a one-off project.  It's not good practice, as stevenh rightly points out, so if this is a design you intend to produce or publish, you should think twice about doing this.

Comment: The only thing that the pin does is pull the line to ground when the Arduino is on. Would this be better implemented with a PNP transistor?

Comment: OK, the target has moved, hasn't it?  The original question was "is this safe".  My answer is that, since the current is very low, the pin voltages are unlikely to exceed the maximum rating *which you can verify if you simply measure the darn pins in question when the micro is unpowered*.   Now, you're asking how to do it differently so I'm assuming you're giving up on the original question?

Comment: Yes, I was asking side questions. If you don't want to answer them, then I understand.

Comment: It's not that I'm not interested in answering them, it's that if the question has changed, start a new question thread and let's deal with it there.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I should have created a new question. I think I have it all worked out, though.